# multiselect biding after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, multi-select

i have this code :

```
    $('body').live('mousemove mouseover', function () {

    $("#parent_task").multiselect({
        selectedList: 4,
       click: function(event, ui){
            var cntInput=$("#child_task").multiselect("widget").find('input[value='+ui.value+']').parent('label');
            if(ui.checked){ cntInput.hide() }else{cntInput.show() }
       }

    }).multiselectfilter();
    $("#child_task").multiselect({
        selectedList: 4,
       click: function(event, ui){
            var cntInput=$("#parent_task").multiselect("widget").find('input[value='+ui.value+']').parent('label');
            if(ui.checked){ cntInput.hide() }else{cntInput.show() }
       }
    }).multiselectfilter();

});
```

how is possible to  start multiselect after ajax load , right now i'm using `$('body').live('mousemove mouseover', function () {` , but is biding after mouse over or mouse move , and it doesn't look good ,  exist another way ? thank you ;)
link to plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ 
Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think you could call multiselect() after AJAX completes or in the succcess function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: yoururl,
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
            //do what you need to do and then initialize the multiselect

    $("#parent_task").multiselect({
        selectedList: 4,
       click: function(event, ui){
            var cntInput=$("#child_task").multiselect("widget").find('input[value='+ui.value+']').parent('label');
            if(ui.checked){ cntInput.hide() }else{cntInput.show() }
       }

    }).multiselectfilter();
    $("#child_task").multiselect({
        selectedList: 4,
       click: function(event, ui){
            var cntInput=$("#parent_task").multiselect("widget").find('input[value='+ui.value+']').parent('label');
            if(ui.checked){ cntInput.hide() }else{cntInput.show() }
       }
    }).multiselectfilter();

 }
```

In this way your DOM is ready and you can call the plugin.

Comment: Thank you , is my mistake , i forgot about this :)