# jQuery Multiselect delegate event using "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am familiar with using "on" for making sure my jquery methods are active (since I render pages via Ajax).

Ex:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '#demobutton', function (event) {
    alert("CliCKED!");
});
```

However I need to do the same for jQuery Multiselect. Below works only when the page is reloaded. However if my content is loaded via Ajax, MultiSelect does not render at all.

```
$("select").multiselect({
   click: function(event, ui){
      alert(ui.value + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked') );



   },
   beforeopen: function(){
      $callback.text("Select about to be opened...");
   },
   open: function(){
      $callback.text("Select opened!");
   },
   beforeclose: function(){
      $callback.text("Select about to be closed...");
   },
   close: function(){
      $callback.text("Select closed!");
   },
   checkAll: function(){
      $callback.text("Check all clicked!");
   },
   uncheckAll: function(){
      $callback.text("Uncheck all clicked!");
   },
   optgrouptoggle: function(event, ui){
      var values = $.map(ui.inputs, function(checkbox){
         return checkbox.value;
      }).join(", ");





      alert("CheckboXES " + (ui.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked") + ": " + values);

   }
});
```

So the question is how to rewrite above using a format such as $('body').on ? Thanks for any help. Newbie here!

Comment: can you include a jsfiddle

Comment: not sure how much I can illustrate in the jsfiddle .... http://jsfiddle.net/WtvN2/2/

Comment: where is your HTML ? you just pasted code in fiddle, which i can do. The point in adding fiddle was to show what you have implemented so far.

Comment: Sorry about that - didn't realize my paste was gone. http://jsfiddle.net/6S6AG/1/ - thanks Dave. I want to modify the same for handling delegates using "on" but don't have the right syntax...

Comment: I found this to be addressing a similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326161/multiselect-biding-after-ajax-load -- gonna try this and post back

Comment: i was about to give that solution, which is best, but your question says to create multiselect with jquery delegate event.

Comment: alternative approach i created ,, does this suits your needs http://jsfiddle.net/6S6AG/3/

Answer (score 0):

since you specified (However if my content is loaded via Ajax, MultiSelect does not render at all.)

here i am loading select options with ajax and binding multiselect [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6S6AG/4/) . Let me know if this helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
        var form_data = $("#frm").serialize();
        var form_url = $("#frm").attr("action");
        var form_method = $("#frm").attr("method").toUpperCase();

        $("#loadingimg").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){     
                alert('binded options to select on ajax success');
                $.when(assignOptions()).done(function(){
                  bind();
                });              
            }           
        });    
});

function assignOptions(){
  $("#display_list").append('<option value="W1">VICccccc</option><option value="W2">NSW</option><option value="W6">TAS 3</option>');
}
function bind(){    
  $("select").multiselect({
   click: function(event, ui){
      alert(ui.value + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked') );

   },
   beforeopen: function(){
      $callback.text("Select about to be opened...");
   },
   open: function(){
      $callback.text("Select opened!");
   },
   beforeclose: function(){
      $callback.text("Select about to be closed...");
   },
   close: function(){
      $callback.text("Select closed!");
   },
   checkAll: function(){
      $callback.text("Check all clicked!");
   },
   uncheckAll: function(){
      $callback.text("Uncheck all clicked!");
   },
   optgrouptoggle: function(event, ui){
      var values = $.map(ui.inputs, function(checkbox){
         return checkbox.value;
      }).join(", ");

      alert("CheckboXES " + (ui.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked") + ": " + values);

   }
});
}
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing worked so far. the fiddle you wrote does seem to address my case but something else at play here. Does it matter if the calling/current page itself was rendered via ajax (in which case there won't be any html to append the #display_list to)? My flow is like this. Login page -> click sign-in button -> render page two via ajax -> do something on page 2 and click next -> page 3 is rendered via ajax. This page 3 contains the multiselect and it just displays a selection list without the jquery multiselect plugin benefit. If I reload page 3 directly, then loads fine.

Comment: (page 3 is rendered via ajax,  This page 3 contains the multiselect and it just displays a selection list ) on success of this ajax you can call bind() function in my jsfiddle which will apply multiselect plugin.

Comment: by the way, my firebug shows a few errors that happen only for the ajax calls - please see http://tinypic.com/r/2ztcd9e/8

Comment: yes Dave, that's what I do. My $.ajax below ->   $.ajax({
    
     url: '/myapp/index.php/translate/view',
     type: "POST",
     data: form_data,
     cache: false,      
     success: function(result) { 
      
      
      alert('binded options to select on ajax success');
      $.when(assignOptions()).done(function(){
       bind();
      });
    
      $('#main_container').html(result);
 
     }
     
    });

Comment: did you compared with external resources in jsfiddle, are you missing something.

Comment: Since your are loading entire page with ajax.. Firstly, check if the new page rendered via ajax has multiselect library included, ans second, try using setTimeOut function inside ajax success to test if function is getting executed with success.

Comment: Dave, I checked both your suggestions. libraries are ok. Ajax success also confirmed. I have stripped down and shared my files http://bit.ly/1jcNWBn to make it easier... if you could give it a go, would be grateful :) –

Comment: CodeIgniter Files
------------------
simple to run - doesn't need a database. 
http://localhost/matrix (just click on sign-in without any credentials)
\xampp\htdocs\matrix\assets\js\utils.js

\xampp\htdocs\matrix\application\views\login_form_view.php   (first page)
\xampp\htdocs\matrix\application\views\landing_area_view.php (second page)

\xampp\htdocs\matrix\application\controllers\site.php
\xampp\htdocs\matrix\application\controllers\login.php

Really appreciate your kind help!

Comment: sorry but i am not familiar with PHP. My familiarity is with .NET & ROR apps... any other alternative approach ?

Comment: the bind wasn't working since the jquery scripts were not loaded on time. I configured local scripts instead of CDN and that did the magic! Problem solved for me.

Comment: i had doubt on scripts getting loaded or not.. however, you solved it,, good... cheers!